# How to prevent PWA from opening links and Auth0 single sign in authentication in new Safari Window

Tags: angular, auth0, progressive-web-apps

I have an issue, I've created an angular PWA and my app uses auth0-lock as its authentication now my problem is.. when you click one of the single sign-in options like Google, for example, you get taken out of the PWA and into safari, Is there any way I can prevent this??

I have tried putting this code in my index.html

```
<!-- Prevent app from opening new safari page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(document,navigator,standalone) {
        // prevents links from apps from oppening in mobile safari
        // this javascript must be the first script in your <head>
        if ((standalone in navigator) && navigator[standalone]) {
            var curnode, location=document.location, stop=/^(a|html)$/i;
            document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                curnode=e.target;
                while (!(stop).test(curnode.nodeName)) {
                    curnode=curnode.parentNode;
                }
                // Condidions to do this only on links to your own app
                // if you want all links, use if('href' in curnode) instead.
                if('href' in curnode && ( curnode.href.indexOf('http') || ~curnode.href.indexOf(location.host) ) ) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    location.href = curnode.href;
                }
            },false);
        }
    })(document,window.navigator,'standalone');
</script>
```

but that doesn't seem to be working, I have seen some other javascript hacks that can prevent this and I have still yet to find one that works in my angular application?

Does anyone have any experience with this??

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's not particular to Angular but to PWA. Apple changed behaviour in iOS 11.3 following new [PWA manifest rules](https://github.com/w3c/manifest/issues/550).

The issue is known and [Apple will be working on it](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pinafore/issues/45).

Unfortunately, it means that there is not much to do in PWA for iOS 11.3…